# Why does SKView! keep on returning nil?

Tags: swift

```
func died(){
    var scene = EndGame(size : self.size)
    let skView = self.view as SKView!
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.size = skView.bounds.size
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

I'm making a simple shooter game and when the character dies I want to redirect him so a separate screen. However when I run this code and the character dies I just get "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: On which line are you getting that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  func died(){
    var scene = EndGame(size: self.size)
    let skView = self.view as SKView?
    skView?.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    scene.size = skView.bounds.size
    skView?.presentScene(scene)
  }
```

I had this same problem and setting the skView to optional seems to fix it. I have not figured out exactly why nil was returned in the first place but this solves the problem, at least for me. Somehow declaring the skView as an optional prevents nil from being returned and prevents this problem. Happy coding.